# Выбор подхода для написания системы

Tags: php, python, django, веб-программирование

Есть ERP система, парус. Крутится на oracle базе.
Система не обладает ни веб интерфейсом ни мобильными приложениями. 
Сейчас там разработана система мм пользователь составляет заявку - кидает туда - дальше там всякие бухгалтерско экономические дела по ее оплате. Грубо говоря небольшая система электронного документа оборота.
Отправка заявки на данный момент реализована через макросы в экселе, оракл модули на компьютерах, извращенно короче.
Требуется перенести этот механизм в web.
Что требуется в вебе - авторизация по учетным записям оракл, не большой дашборд мм грубо говоря выборками из всего списка заявок (сколько согласовано, сколько отправелно и так далее), возможность составить заявку там (заполнить 10 полей, приложить файлик, нажать кнопку отправить и данные загружаются в оракл базу), возможность просмотреть заявки, которые ожидают согласования.

Собственно вопрос. Для работы над этим будет нанят человек, может не один, т.к. я не хочу аутсорс да и свой разработчик давно требуется и нужно понимать, как оптимальнее сделать данный процесс. 
Питон+джанго или пхп или может есть более подходящие варианты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Питон+джанго или пхп или может есть более подходящие варианты.

Выполнить задачу подобную Вашей, можно на любом стеке web технологий. В первую очередь важно:

- Чётко поставить задачу. Тогда результат на выходе будет значительно ближе к ожидаемому;
- Чтобы в тех бизнес процессах, которые предстоит автоматизировать не было бардака. Иначе ничего, кроме автоматизированного бардака Вы не получите, а время и деньги потратите.

Что же касается конкретного стека технологий, его выбор лучше доверить исполнителю по результатам предпроектного анализа.